# ValueProxy to automatically serialize 3rd party objects

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using Solrj library to communicate from server class to Solr. To transfer objects to client I'm currently creating new DTO objects and use setters to copy the data.

Copying the data manually, especially, when you have multiple DTO objects is not a nice way.

I'm considering to use `RequestFactory` and `ValueProxy` to map my proxy classes to Solrj classes. As I understood, I don't need `EntityProxy`, because Solrj objects don't have an id. It's just a collection of objects, which I don't persist.

Would it make sense to use RequestFactory in this case? Do I need all this Locators and other interfaces used by RF?

There is not much information on this topic, especially on `ValueProxy`'s. Reference would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched from using gwt rpc to request factory for everything mainly because I now can transfer any object to the client without modifying the third party classes to implement serializable. You do not have to have a locator you can simply use use an implementation with a static methods. If you do not wish to make them static you can simply implement the [ServiceLocator](https://github.com/chinshaw/simple-original/blob/master/ui/src/main/java/com/simple/original/server/service/SchedulerService.java) in your server package and add the locator=WhateverYourServiceIs.class to the @Service annotation

Here is my version I use for accessing the [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler objects from the server.

**Client Code**

```
    @Service(value = SchedulerService.class)
    public interface SchedulerRequest extends RequestContext {

        Request<List<QuartzTriggerProxy>> getScheduledJobs();

        Request<List<QuartzTriggerProxy>> searchSchedules(String searchString);

        Request<Void> unscheduleJob(String keyName, String groupName);

        Request<Void> pauseTrigger(QuartzTriggerKeyProxy triggerKey);

        Request<Void> resumeTrigger(QuartzTriggerKeyProxy triggerKey);

        Request<QuartzTriggerProxy> getTrigger(String keyName, String groupName);

        Request<Void> fireTriggerNow(QuartzTriggerKeyProxy triggerKey);

        Request<Void> fireJobNow(QuartzJobKeyProxy jobKey);

        Request<Date> rescheduleJob(QuartzTriggerKeyProxy triggerKey, QuartzTriggerProxy trigger);

        Request<AnalyticsTaskProxy> getTaskForTrigger(QuartzJobKeyProxy jobKey);

        Request<String> getTriggerState(QuartzTriggerKeyProxy triggerKey);

    }
```

**Service Code**

```
public class SchedulerService {

    public static void pauseTrigger(TriggerKey triggerKey) throws AnalyticsTaskException, SchedulerException {
        getTaskEngine().pauseTrigger(triggerKey);
    }

    public static void resumeTrigger(TriggerKey triggerKey) throws AnalyticsTaskException, SchedulerException {
        getTaskEngine().resumeTrigger(triggerKey);
    }

    public static Trigger getTrigger(String keyName, String groupName) throws AnalyticsTaskException, SchedulerException {
        return getTaskEngine().getTrigger(TriggerKey.triggerKey(keyName, groupName));
    }

    public static void fireTriggerNow(TriggerKey triggerKey) throws AnalyticsTaskException, SchedulerException {
     getTaskEngine().fireTriggerNow(triggerKey);
    }

    public static void fireJobNow(JobKey jobKey) throws AnalyticsTaskException, SchedulerException {
     getTaskEngine().fireJobNow(jobKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for answering. I wrote some code that hopefully will work. But I have an error: "The domain type twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl cannot be sent to the client". It's because I created a proxy for abstract `Status` class and not for `StatusJSONImpl`. I saw that I have to use `@ExtraTypes`, but this child class is private and I can't reference it from outside. Can I solve this?

Comment: That sucks, not sure how to work around that unless you create your own implementation of the Status class and then add a copy constructor to map the properties and point your proxy to this implementation.